# Other endpoints are ignored when using express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Post = require('./models/Post');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const path = require('path');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../react-app/build')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../react-app/build', 
 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
   Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
     if(err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.sendStatus(500);
     } else {
       res.send(posts)
     }  

   })
 });

 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

I've builded my react frontend to the location specified in the path.join. However, if I use the `app.use(express.static(...))`, if I use any path at all, it will always return index.html from my build.

I'd like to see the posts object when I got to '/posts' endpoint, but it doesn't work and I can't get the build serving working without express static.

EDIT:
I tried console logging inside '/' handler, but it logged nothing either. I got everything working when I remove the app.use line entirely. Some tutorials use this approach, why is not working?

Comment: see if your `/posts` request is hitting `/` handler. use debugger or console log. Then add more information to this question if answer wouldn't be obvious.

Comment: They don't even hit the '/' handler, why is this?

Comment: Try switching `/` and `/posts` handlers order. It will respond to first handler matched. So maybe it hits the `/` matches it and replies, without doing any other work. @Miika

Comment: @zmii This is not working. As I said before, I tried console logging inside the first endpoint, but it doesn't end up even inside of it. Seems like it completely ignores the endpoints and serves only the static content.

Answer (score 1):

So try this:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Post = require('./models/Post');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const path = require('path');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../react-app/build')));

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
   Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
     if(err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.sendStatus(500);
     } else {
       res.send(posts)
     }  

   })
 });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../react-app/build', 
 'index.html'));
});

 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`));
```